# sort mulitdimensional array in php according to specific column

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a mulitdimensional array according to a field in the inner array, like this:

```
$result = array(
  array("first" => 1, "second" => 5),
  array("first" => 3, "second" => 8),
  array("first" => 6, "second" => 7),
  array("first" => 6, "second" => 1)
);

sort($result,"second");

/*
$result = array(
  array("first" => 6, "second" => 1),
  array("first" => 1, "second" => 5),
  array("first" => 6, "second" => 7),
  array("first" => 3, "second" => 8)
);
*/
```

Is there something like the intended sort function here in PHP or do I have to reimplement that?

Comment: Can you show what result you want here?

Comment: like the one in the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for this

> This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['second'] == $b['second']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['second'] < $b['second']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

You can even sort of 'second' first and 'first' second :) (sort on 'first' if 'second' is the same)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['second'] == $b['second']) {
        if ($a['first'] == $b['first']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['first'] < $b['first']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a['second'] < $b['second']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is very much simple function for sorting array.

```
function sort_by_key($a, $subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    asort($b);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}
```

You can call it like this in your case:

```
sort_by_key($result , 'second');
```